# Android AWS APIGateway Client Exception (Code 100)

Tags: java, android, json, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying upload a base64 image that is converted to a string. When sending the string I am getting a ApiClientException. The base64 image looks something like this:

{"base64String":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAMCAgMCAgMDAwMEAwMEBQgFBQQEBQoHB......"}

I create a JSONObject to store the base64 data then convert it to a string (which is the reason the data is encapsulated above).

```
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: {"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'d\' (code 100)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: [B@31587f68; line: 2, column: 17]"} (Service: AllyantsAPIClient; Status Code: 400; Error Code: null; Request ID: 9f2f752d-fc9a-11e7-8d90-517849cc68d9)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The  error is 400:

```
400 Bad Request Exception
```

Thats mean sends some invalid data in the request, incorrect content  or parameters. The error is in your side.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to be a bad AWS APIGateway SDK, I redeployed my APIGateway and generated the SDK again for Android and the problem went away.